# Laravel : if else in Eloquent create method. Can I do like this?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
ModelName::create([                                                                                                             
     'body' => if(isset($request->input('someText')) ? 1 : 0;
]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... well you can use a ternary but they don't start with an `if`

Comment: You could probably just do `'body' => $request->has("someText")` instead, or if you're set on using `isset()`, then `'body' => isset($request->input('someText')`. I'd go with the first one.

Comment: 'body'=>$request->has("someText") ? 1 : 0;  Like this?

Comment: @user327534 that method returns a boolean so if you had to convert that into an integer you can  `(int) $request->has('someText')`

Comment: I don't really think you need to typecast it to integer, as it'll end up as `1` or `0` for a boolean `true` or `false` respectively. A simple `'body' => $request->has("someText")` should suffice.

Comment: @Qirel to me that would depend if it is being converted to a string or not after the fact, that is my only worry

Comment: I think this would be enough `'body' => $request->has('someText') `